# Android Canvas Path to Bitmap

Tags: android, path

I have an bitmap that I want to apply an alpha mask to. I know I can easily use Porter Duff mode to do that with another bitmap, but I want to programmatically create the alpha mask because it needs to change continually. So, I'm trying to use a path to create it, but I can't make the connection between the finished path and creating the bitmap to use from that path.

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar_percent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:progress="50" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_canvas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar_percent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.wheeler.daniel.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    PathRectangle alphaPath;
    ImageView canvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        canvas = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_canvas);

        canvas.post(new Runnable() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                int canvasWidth = display.getWidth();
                int canvasHeight = display.getHeight();

                alphaPath = new PathRectangle(getApplicationContext(), canvas, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            }
        });



        SeekBar percentBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar_percent);
        percentBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){

                alphaPath.updatePercent(progress);
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

I created a class to draw my path (a basic rectangle to cover the image) called PathRectangle:

```
public class PathRectangle extends View {
    ImageView   layoutCanvas;
    Bitmap      canvasBitmap;
    Paint       paint;
    Path        path;
    float       width;
    float       height;
    int         percent;
    Canvas      tempCanvas;

    public PathRectangle(Context context, ImageView canvasImage, float width, float height)
    {
        super(context);

        layoutCanvas = canvasImage;

        path = new Path();

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        percent = 50;

        Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, config);
        tempCanvas = new Canvas( canvasBitmap );

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(0,0);
        path.lineTo(percent, 0);
        path.lineTo(percent, height);
        path.lineTo(0, height);

        tempCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        layoutCanvas.setImageBitmap(canvasBitmap);

    }

    public void updatePercent(int newPercent)
    {
        percent = (int) (width * (newPercent * .01));

        invalidate();
    }

}
```

This is just my testing to generate the Bitmap, but nothing is displayed in my ImageView. I feel like by drawing the path to the tempCanvas isn't actually drawing it to the bitmap I used in the creation of the tempCanvas.

Example of what I want:
Source Bitmap
[image: Source]

Alpha Mask to create
[image: Alpha Mask]

Result
[image: Result]

Comment: did you try a BitnapHader?

Comment: btw what you are trying to do in that particular case can be done with simple Canvas.drawBitmap,  see all mutations of this method

Comment: I have tried a BitmapShader where the shader basically painted the fill of the path with the Bitmap I originally wanted to apply an alpha mask to: 

Bitmap shader = new BitmapShader(imageToDisplay, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
...
strokePaint.setShader(shader);
canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint);

But when I draw this to a canvas after other Bitmaps then it applies the transparency to everything.

Comment: I cannot use any of the Canvas.drawBitmap() methods because I want to draw multiple images each with an alpha mask that is created programmatically using a filled path.

Comment: i dont understand  what you mean

Comment: post an image of what you want to achieve

Comment: I have a Bitmap that I want to apply an alpha mask to. I want to create this mask in code. The only way I have found to make the shapes that I need for the alpha mask are by using a Path. Path's are drawn to canvases, not Bitmaps. But in order for me to apply an alpha mask to a Bitmap I must use another Bitmap. So, I cannot find a way to convert this path into a Bitmap to use as the alpha mask.

Comment: seen new Canvas(Bitmap)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59430/discussion-between-hososugi-and-pskink).